# Using GWT RequestFactory on iOS devices

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, gwt, requestfactory, iphone-web-app

An Android app can use RequestFactories to access data from GWT applications. Thats a very simple and great solution. See http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/ for more information.

My Question:

- Is there a way to use RequestFactories on iOS devices? Is there a
- Library/Framework which can be implemented in iOS Projects?

kindest regards

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there isn't any open-sourced library to use RequestFactory in ios projects.

What you can do is to develop a standard gwt app and package it with phonegap aka [cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/).

I'm using gwt + [mgwt](http://www.m-gwt.com/) + [gwtphonegap](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/) in my apps and they run quite well.

Comment: Your answer does not answer my question.I don't know any open-source library, for this propose. I already have developed a gwt + mgwt + gwtphonegap app. but i want to develop a native app, which communicates via requesfactories - thats why i'm asking this question.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to use RF in native IOS right now, it should be possible to write your own code to talk with a RF server since the comunication is json, but there are a lot of things to consider to implement the dialog, and it is not trivial.

Comment: Yes, i believe that that will no be trivial. But if i need it, i will do it. I will leave the question opened, maybe somebody has already done it, but not published it. If somebody decide to develop a webapp, gwt+mgwt is enought, but you will have a lot of downsides, which is not acceptable in high end business applications. You know what I mean?

Comment: Yes I know, although phonegap + gwt matches well my requirements (not only for web), I have developed a very visual app using canvas (playn) and some plugins,  performing quite well. I think if you go ahead porting RF, it could be easier to change the server code and offer json additionally to RF. Anyway let's see if hopefully  someone has worked in this line before.

Comment: Unfortunately I believe manolo is right, there is no library for iOS, I've spent sometime surfing the Internet and the only page I've seen about porting RF client to another language was a post in the gwt-developers list about how easy should be port it to Dart.